# Develop on Windodows and Build - Deploy on Linux with Vagrant?

Tags: linux, maven, vagrant

It is possible to write code for some Maven Projet on Windows and then Build and Deploy that project on a Linux Machine with Vagrant?

Answer (score 1):

It is totally possible to do so as you generally develop locally on windows/mac and deliver your code on to your ops team which will deploy on a *nix machine

[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) is just a tool to abstract your virtualization tool. so if you're using VirtualBox vagrant does a lot of automatic configuration for you, including [shared folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html)

1. Install vagrant/virtualbox
2. Get a vagrant box for the OS you want to work on
3. Install maven on your VM (or provision the installation of the tool)
4. work locally and share the project folder with your VM
5. build and deploy on the VM